# AngularJS select element selects question mark value, ngmodel related

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

For some reason my `ng-model` is not valid against select options compiled by AngularJS. This is common problem but I did not find a solution that works here.
The select is inside tr element repeated by `ng-repeat`.

This is my select, ng-model in most cases equals to `1`, but an extra question mark option is selected instead:

```html
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-touched"
        ng-model="item.parent_id" ng-change="validateRow(item)"
        ng-options="option as option.name for option in options_parent_names track by option.id">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option label="Moja Firma" value="1">Moja Firma</option>
    <option label="Dział Finansowy" value="74">Dział Finansowy</option>
    <option label="Biuro obsługi klienta" value="76">Biuro obsługi klienta</option>
    <option label="Magazyn" value="77">Magazyn</option>
    <option label="Dział zamówień" value="78">Dział zamówień</option>
    <option label="Dział X" value="80">Dział X</option>
    <option label="Inny dział" value="91">Inny dział</option>
    <option label="Dział Y" value="92">Dział Y</option>
    <option label="Dział Z" value="93">Dział Z</option>
</select>
```

- I am using `track by` which helps by removing `number:` part from option value attribute
- Tried `convert-to-number` directive but that does not change anything.
- Tried ng-repeat instead of ng-options
- Tried generating options by PHP but that does nothing more than spamming HTML
- Tried using ng-value in options
- Tried `ng-model` with `| number` filter
- Tried casting value to number before it goes into ng-model

Answer (score 0):

What eventually worked out was generating options in HTML with no ng-options.